# How do I associate four models through a single join table on one form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, nested-attributes, has-many-through, model-associations

I have Classroom, Instructor, Task, and Trainee models that I am attempting to associate through a Credit join model using multiple has_many through associations.  Each record in the Credit model would have a task_id, trainee_id, instructor_id, and classroom_id.

```
class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :credits, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :trainees, through: :credits
  has_many :instructors, through: :credits
  has_many :tasks, through: :credits

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :credits
end

class Instructor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :credits
  has_many :classrooms, through: :credits
  has_many :trainees, through: :credits
  has_many :tasks, through: :credits
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :credits
  has_many :classrooms, through: :credits
  has_many :trainees, through: :credits
  has_many :instructors, through: :credits
end

class Trainee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :credits
  has_many :classrooms, through: :credits
  has_many :instructors, through: :credits
  has_many :tasks, through: :credits
end

class Credit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :classroom
  belongs_to :instructor
  belongs_to :trainee
  belongs_to :task
end
```

I would like to be able to create multiple records in my join model through the new Classrooms form.  For example, when I select one Instructor (select box), three students (checkboxes), and three tasks (checkboxes) I would create 9 records each with a task_id, trainee_id, instructor_id, and classroom_id.  The solution I am looking for would iterate over each Trainee and Task to have multiple, complete records.

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for :classroom, url: classrooms_path do |f| %>

        <%= f.text_field :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :location %>
        <%= f.date_select :date %>
        <%= f.time_select :start_time, label: "Start Time" %>
        <%= f.time_select :end_time, label: "End Time" %>

        <%= f.select :instructor_ids, Instructor.all.collect {|x| [x.rank + " " + x.last_name, x.id]}, {} %>

        <table class="table table-sm">
          <tr>
            <th>Trainee</th>
            <th>Battery</th>
            <th>Crew</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Add</th>
          </tr>

          <% Trainee.all.each do |trainee| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= trainee.rank %> <%= trainee.first_name %> <%= trainee.last_name %></td>
              <td><%= trainee.battery %></td>
              <td><%= trainee.crew %></td>
              <td><%= trainee.position %></td>
              <td><%= check_box_tag :trainee_ids, trainee.id, @classroom.trainees.include?(trainee), :name => 'classroom[trainee_ids][]' -%></td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>

          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <th>Task</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Add</th>
          </tr>

          <% Task.all.each do |task| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= task.title %></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td><%= check_box_tag :task_ids, task.id, @classroom.tasks.include?(task), :name => 'classroom[task_ids][]' -%></td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </table>

        <%= f.submit "Schedule Training", class: "btn btn-success" %>
```

So far I have been successful in making classroom_id associations to the other selections as seen below.  However, I cannot figure out how to iterate through each of the Instructor, Trainee, and Task combinations to create multiple, complete records.

[Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPcvp.png)

I have added my Classrooms Controller below for completeness.

```
class ClassroomsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @classrooms = Classroom.all
  end

  def show
    @classroom = Classroom.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @classroom = Classroom.new
  end

  def edit
    @classroom = Classroom.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @classroom = Classroom.new(classroom_params)

    if @classroom.save
      redirect_to classrooms_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @classroom = Classroom.find(params[:id])

    if @classroom.update(classroom_params)
      redirect_to classrooms_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @classroom = Classroom.find(params[:id])
    @classroom.destroy

    redirect_to classrooms_path
  end

  private
    def classroom_params
      params.require(:classroom).permit(:title, :location, :date, :start_time, :end_time, :instructor_ids, trainee_ids: [], task_ids: [])
    end
end
```

I have searched far and wide looking for a solution, but nothing seems to fit.  Is there someway to do multiple for loops to make this work?  I assume this would occur in the controller, but I am unsure of how to make this happen.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you would need multiple loops to make this work. You'd need to loop through the `params[:classroom][:trainee_ids]` to pull the trainee IDs and then associate them with the classroom. Here's a quick example (and a nice one-liner): `@classroom.trainee_ids = params[:classroom][:trainee_ids]`. You would then do this for all of the other associations.

Comment: Is there anyway that you can post a more complete recommendation?  I am having a hard time wrapping my head around this one.  I looked up how to iterate over the params, but am getting stuck.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I certainly can. Here's a quick snippet I wrote up: http://ideone.com/lobw0Z. I'm still not clear on what you're trying to do exactly. Do you want to associate all of the `Trainees` and `Tasks` with that one, new `Classroom`?

Comment: So... thanks to your help I can now save a complete record.  Now I have to figure out how to prevent the incomplete records from being saved.  Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome! In your `create` action, you might want to try a check for `valid?` instead of saving outright: `if @classroom.valid? # Do everything else`. [Click here for docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html#method-i-valid-3F). Also, please make sure to post your final answer so people looking at this question in the future can refer to it!